# How to trigger Position Absolute validation engine function to validate the fields on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

I am using a jQuery validation engine by position absolute. The function gets triggered on submit and the function is called when dom is ready.

**Position Absolute Function trigger**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
    jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
});
```

The above function is a basic initialization of the function. When the dom is ready, the function is triggered and when the form with FormID is submitted it will validate the form.

But i want to make it validate the fields by clicking a button instead of a submit button.

```
<input type="button" value="validate" id="next" name="next">
```

The reason why i want to do is because am using validation in a wizard, the submit button will be in the last step of the form. but there will be next buttons in every field to go to the next page of the form wizard. I want to validate the fields in the first page  when the next button in the first page is clicked.

Please tell me how can i do it ?

**Position Absolute validation engine**

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would do it this way:

```
function ValidateForm() 
{
    return $('#formID').validationEngine({ returnIsValid: true });
}
```

and then add the following in the click event for button:

```
if (ValidateForm()==false) return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery( '#next' ).click(function(){
    return $( '#formID' ).validationEngine( 'validate' );
});
```